# Terraform: Give permissions to ElastiCache user to export to S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-elasticache

I would like to export snapshots from ElastiCache to S3. This is relatively easy to set up manually by following [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups-exporting.html#backups-exporting-grant-access). However, I would like to do this programatically by using terraform.

In the documentation it states:

```
5. Choose Access Control List.

<snip />

8. Set the permissions on the bucket by choosing Yes for:
   a. List objects
   b. Write objects
   c. Read bucket permissions
```

I haven't been able to find anywhere in [the Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket.html) where I can set these permissions on the bucket. I did find [some documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#permissions) that maps the above permissions to IAM policies permissions and I applied these in the bucket policy. Unfortunately, I still get the following error:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CopySnapshot operation: Elasticache has not been granted ReadACP permissions on the S3 bucket my-backups

**CODE**

Setting up S3 Bucket:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "my_backups" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "s3:GetBucketAcl",
      "s3:ListBucket",
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:DeleteObject",
    ]

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::my-backups",
      "arn:aws:s3:::my-backups/*",
    ]

    principals {
      type        = "CanonicalUser"
      identifiers = ["540804c33a284a299d2547575ce1010f2312ef3da9b3a053c8bc45bf233e4353"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_backups" {
  bucket = "my-backups"
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.my_backups.json}"
}
```

**GITHUB**

I found two issues (with code that hasn't been merged) that relate to this:

1. [Support bucket ACLs](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/3757)
2. [Implementation of acl grants](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/3728)

I'm guessing this may not be possible until one of these two issues is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error it appears that you're ElasticCache principal, cannot read the buckets access control policy permissions. You need to add some additional permissions specifically based on this page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups-exporting.html#backups-exporting-grant-access

```
{
"Statement":
    {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
        ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Comment: I get the same 'Elasticache has not been granted ReadACP permissions' error